# Erorr Message Related to Connect Online Database With Vb.net Program

Tags: vb.net

**I`m able to connect The online Database with the VB.net Program and that successfully done.**

The program have Just a `button` & `DataGridView` i just show the data From the **Online Database** on the `DataGridView` by the `button`.

> **The problem** is :  When I click on the `button` I Got ***Error message*** For 1 Time only and After Closing the Error Message if i **Re-click** On the `button` it Shows the Data From the **Online Database**  I would like to Solve this.

The code Of Which Im using :

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim conectionstring As String
        Dim comandtext As String
        Dim con As MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim table As DataTable
        conectionstring = "server=db4free.net;Port=3306; User ID=username; password=*******; database=database"
        comandtext = "select * from Registration"
        Try
            con = New MySqlDataAdapter(comandtext, conectionstring)
            table = New DataTable
            con.Fill(table)
            DataGridView2.DataSource = table
            Dim column As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView2.Columns(0)
            column.Width = 90
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

The **Erorr Message** You Can Click [Here](https://files.gitter.im/Eslam-Alawy/BswX/Capture.PNG) "Because i Can`t Copy It" .

The **OutPut** Of The Program Click [Here](https://files.gitter.im/Eslam-Alawy/bPvW/Capture.PNG).

The Properties of `DataGridView` [Here](https://files.gitter.im/Eslam-Alawy/wTxt/12.PNG) And [Here](https://files.gitter.im/Eslam-Alawy/rphU/13.PNG)

**The Structure Of The Database [Here edited](https://files.gitter.im/Eslam-Alawy/qwAq/33.PNG)**

The OutPut On Database [Here](https://files.gitter.im/Eslam-Alawy/HIeC/2.PNG)

Comment: It does not have anything to do with the connection.  The database contains misleading data that can't be converted correctly.  Googling the error produces this incredibly silly [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60945).  Jeez marie.

Comment: So what i have to do ?

Comment: What does the Create Table command for your Registration table look like?

Comment: please Review The Edit  i Added The Structure Of The Database

Comment: I'm not seeing the Create Table statement.

Comment: I think what HoneyBoy is asking for is the table definition, not a screenshot of the data.  The error you're having suggests there is a GUID field either in the registration table or perhaps even in the column definitions on your datagridview that can not be converted successfully.  Really you haven't given use the information to help too much

Comment: We need to see the datatype and size of each column in the database.

Comment: please Review The Edit i Added The Real Structure  @Honeyboy Wilson  @Hursey @ Mary   if There Anything you need to know Please Tell me  And Im new With Database So If there`s A code for The DataTaple Please Tell me where i can find it im using PhpMyAdmin

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to be the one addressed by the bug report referenced by Hans Passant. I notice that your table does not contain a primary key. You might try assigning one. Every table should have a primary key whether that fixes this particular problem or not.

Comment: ok i`ll try The primary key

Comment: Not Working Still The Error @HoneyboyWilson

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I did see one suggestion that you might try: add the directive "old guids = true" to your connection string. This would result in your connection string looking like this: "server=db4free.net;Port=3306; User ID=username; password=*******; database=database;old guids=true;"

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson Please Write it As An Answer :) it`s Working And please Tell me what That command do ❤❤   Thanks   ❤❤

Comment: and if i can contact you please leave me a contact way ❤